# Separating DB logic by passing blocks

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I'm trying to separate my Parse calls in a `DBManager` object. Here's one of my calls:

```
- (void)createMessageObject:(NSString*)text forConversation:(PFObject*)conversationObject withBlock:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block {

    /////////////////////////////////
    // First create the object
    PFObject* messageObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kWSMessageClassKey];
    [messageObject addObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kWSMessageUserKey];
    [messageObject addObject:text forKey:kWSMessageTextKey];
    [messageObject addObject:[[WSWordlistManager shared] languageTarget] forKey:KWSMessageLanguageKey];


    [messageObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {

            ///////////////////////////////
            // Now add it to the Conversation object
            [conversationObject addObject:messageObject forKey:kWSConversationMessagesKey];
            [conversationObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:block];

        }
    }];
}
```

Right now I'm working on an in-app chat/messaging feature. So in the above call I want to create a new `Message` object and if it saves successfully then add it to an existing `Conversation` object. The problem lies in my original call in my ViewController:

```
  [self createMessageObject:text forConversation:self.conversation withBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (succeeded) {

            // PROBLEM HERE: HOW TO PASS BACK THE messageObject I CREATED IN THE DB CALL?
            [self.objects addObject:messageObject]; 

            [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:text sender:sender date:date]];
            [self finishSend];                
            [self sendMessagePushFromUser:[PFUser currentUser] toUsers:self.friends messageObject:messageObject];                
            [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];

        }

    }];
```

So the problem lies in the line I commented on. I need access to the `messageObject` I created in the Parse call, but how to pass it back?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613642/how-do-i-change-objects-value-passed-as-a-parameter-inside-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback. Something like this:

```
- (void)createMessageObject:(NSString*)text forConversation:(PFObject*)conversationObject withCallback:(void(^)(PFObject *messageObject))callback {
    /////////////////////////////////
    // First create the object
    PFObject* messageObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kWSMessageClassKey];
    [messageObject addObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kWSMessageUserKey];
    [messageObject addObject:text forKey:kWSMessageTextKey];
    [messageObject addObject:[[WSWordlistManager shared] languageTarget] forKey:KWSMessageLanguageKey];


    [messageObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(messageObject);
            }

        }
    }];
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
[self createMessageObject:text forConversation:self.conversation withCallback:^(PFObject *messageObject) {
    NSLog(@"Text from message object: %@", [messageObject objectForKey:kWSMessageTextKey]);

    [self.objects addObject:messageObject];

    [self.messages addObject:[[JSMessage alloc] initWithText:text sender:sender date:date]];
    [self finishSend];
    [self sendMessagePushFromUser:[PFUser currentUser] toUsers:self.friends messageObject:messageObject];
    [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
}];
```