# How do I change object's value (passed as a parameter) inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an POST request block in one of my functions and I want to change the value of an NSString object inside the block.

I realise that normally one could just prefix the variable `__block`, but in my case, want to change the value of an NSString object by directly referencing its parameter.

Here's a code skeleton, with relevant comments.

```
- (void)getItemInformation:(NSString *)inputString{
    //setup stuff
    [manager  POST:@"http://foo.com/iphone_item_string/"
        parameters:parameters
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               //change inputString directly here
               inputString = (NSString *)responseObject[0];
               //this of course gives an error, but I'm
               //unsure of how to use __block with a parameter
           }
               //foo
           }
     ];
}
```

And a segment from the calling function

```
currentEntryData.foo = "lorem";
NSString *retrieveString;
[self getItemInformation:retrieveString];
currentEntryData.bar = retrieveString;
currentEntryData.oof = "ipsum";
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the parameter value? Just use a local variable.

Comment: How is changing the parameter going to help you? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The function calling this one is building data for display to the user. One of the pieces of data requires information from the server (bad practice to use POST, I realise), so instead of cluttering the original function, I made this one to be called. I'll update the description in two tics :)

Comment: If you need to get data returned from the `getItemInformation:` method then setting a value to the parameter will not work. Normally you would have a return value on the method for such a purpose. But since you need to return a value from an asynchronous process, that won't work either. The answer by pacman321 is the proper solution. You need to provide a completion callback that gives you the desired value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use blocks

```
- (void)getItemInformationWithCallback:(void(^)(NSString *resultString))callback {

    [manager POST:@"http://foo.com/iphone_item_string/"
        parameters:parameters
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

               // Here you call the callback block
               //
               NSString *newString = (NSString *)responseObject[0];
               if (callback)
                   callback(newString)
           }
     }];
}
```

And that's how you get the string back

```
[self getItemInformationWithCallback:^(NSString *resultString) {
    NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
}];
```

Comment: One minor suggestion - I wouldn't name the callback parameter `inputString`. `resultString` would probably be a better name.

Comment: Why does this even need to still pass `inputString` as a first parameter to the `getItemInformation:` method? All you have to do is pass the callback block.

Comment: @Gavin Good catch. `inputString` isn't used at all so it should be removed.